# log4net could not load error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, log4net

I had facing an could not load file error after using crystal report.
error as below:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.

I check with property page, log4net version is 2.0.5, is updated by nuget.

after browsed on internet, i add this to my web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="1b44e1d426115821" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.5.0"
                         newVersion="2.0.5.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

but it still not work.
Please help.

UPDATE:
after admin the web.config, it look like this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" PublicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.5.0"
                         newVersion="2.0.5.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

But now a new error stated: Error 11 The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception.

What went wrong?

Comment: You need to use [the version of log4net that still uses the old key](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org//logging/log4net/binaries/log4net-1.2.15-bin-oldkey.zip) - as you can see in your question, the PublicKeyToken in the error message is not the same as the one in your binding redirect.

Comment: I had download the oldkey, but i still don't know how to use it to correct the error. I feel sorry cause i very new to this, can you help me?

Comment: Once you have the version with the old key, change the binding redirect to use `PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304`

Comment: is this what i should do? 1) copy the log4net.dll to project bin, 2) change the publickeytoken above to PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304 ?

Comment: Yes, that should do it. Though I seem to remember Crystal Reports saves log4net to the GAC, which might complicate things. Give it a try.

Comment: I did that, but that is an error stated: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception. when i rebuild the project

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what the binding redirect looks like now?

Comment: new update has been added

Comment: newVersion should be `1.2.15.0` as that's the log4net *assembly* version, and oldVersion should thus be `0.0.0.0-1.2.15.0`

Comment: I changed it, the error still same.